# If $\text{Var}(X) < \text{Var}(Y)$, is $\text{Var} (1/X) < \text{Var}(1/Y)$ for all cases?

Tags: distributions, variance

I have tried this out for a few binomial distributions and it seems to work, but does anyone know if $\text{Var} (1/X) < \text{Var}(1/Y)$ is true for all cases where $\text{Var}(X) < \text{Var}(Y)$? Thanks.

Comment: This might be useful, the mean and variance for the reciprocal normal do not exist. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646428/mean-and-variance-of-reciprocal-normal-distribution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, for the simple fact that $1/X$ or $1/Y$ may not even be valid random variables because of division by zero.  Even if we rule this out there are simple counterexamples.  Consider $X \in \{\epsilon, 1\}$ for $\epsilon \in (0, 2/3)$ and $Y \in \{1, 2 \}$, each taking on these values with equal probability.  Then we have $\text{Var}(X) < \text{Var}(Y)$ but $\text{Var}(1 / X) > \text{Var}(1/Y)$ for any $\epsilon$.

Comment: Cheers! But what if I limit the scope to normally distributed random variables? It seems logical that the proposition holds because as $Var(1/X)$ becomes very small, $Var(X)$ will become very small. Sorry if I'm missing out on something here.

Comment: It's not true in that case either because $\text{Var}(1/X)$ turns out to be infinite when $X$ is normal.  An inverse relationship between $X$ and $1/X$ in no way implies an inverse relationship for the variances.

Comment: @Marcel: For the inverse normal distribution (a special case of generalized inverse normal distribution), all $k$-th moments for $k>1$ are undefined. So variance doesn't exist in the first place.

Comment: @Francis What about binomial distributions? If we know $Var(\hat{p})=\frac{p(1-p)}{N}$, can $Var(1/\hat{p})$ be found?

Comment: You still have division by zero there.

Comment: @Marcel: As dsaxton pointed out, inverse of Binomial r.v. is not valid due to division by 0. However, you might be able to find explicit formula for zero-truncated or shifted Binomial r.v. [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497976/reciprocal-of-a-binomial) and [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0511226.pdf) may be helpful.